# Upload files to a SFTP server with VB.NET (Visual Basic)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am creating a program that allows you to send files to a shared server. Unfortunately I built the program by uploading it to an FTP server, but I realized that the connection is not secure and with a network packet manager you could easily find my server's username and password. I therefore opted for an SFTP server which should be the secure version of FTP. Unfortunately I can't use it.

I tried with these codes, which work perfectly with ftp but with sftp not.

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\Path\file.txt", "sftp://server.net/path/file.txt", "username", "password")
```

```
Dim WithEvents upload as New WebClient
upload.uploadfileasync("C:\path","sftp://adress")
```

I repeat, both works with ftp, but not with sftp. They gave this error. "prefix is not supported" or something similar.
I tryed to use Renci's SSH.NET external library

```
Dim WithEvents client As Renci.SshNet.SftpClient = New Renci.SshNet.SftpClient("website", "username", "password")
    client.Connect()
    Using stream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\Path")
        client.UploadFile(stream, "/path")
    End Using
```

But i can't use the event FileUploadCompleted or ProgressChanged and i need it!

 i putted "WithEvents" before the name of the var but nothing changed.

 Please help me!

(Sorry for my bad english and my poor programming skills)
Thanks!

Comment: See the UploadFile method overload or the BeginUploadFile method. Both allow to specify callbacks that notify the operation progress and termination (the same with  the DownloadFile and BeginDownloadFile methods).

Comment: Jimi How can i do that? Can you send me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am using this code in my project. please check it.

```
Public Function UploadFile(strFileLocalFullPath As String, strRemoteUploadPath As String) As Boolean
            Try
                Using session As New Session()
                    session.SessionLogPath = "your log path"
                    session.Open(sessionOptions)
                    Dim transferOptions As New TransferOptions()
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary
                    transferOptions.FilePermissions = Nothing
                    transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = False
                    transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.Off

                    Dim transferResult As TransferOperationResult
                    transferResult = session.PutFiles(strFileLocalFullPath, strRemoteUploadPath, False, transferOptions)
                    transferResult.Check()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                'Log Exception here
                Return False
            End Try

            Return True
        End Function
```